# NSArray of character strings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an NSMutableArray of characters.

```
lowerCaseLetters = [NSMutableArray new];
for (char crt = 'a'; crt <= 'z'; crt ++) {
    NSString *chrStr = [NSString stringWithCString:&crt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [lowerCaseLetters addObject:chrStr];
}
NSLog(@"%@",lowerCaseLetters);
```

Result:

```
  "a@Ip",
    "b@Ip",
    "c@Ip",
    "d@Ip",
    "e@Ip",
    "f@Ip",
    "g@Ip",
    "h@Ip",
    "i@Ip",
    "j@Ip",
    "k@Ip",
    "l@Ip",
    "m@Ip",
    "n@Ip",
    "o@Ip",
    "p@Ip",
    "q@Ip",
    "r@Ip",
    "s@Ip",
    "t@Ip",
    "u@Ip",
    "v@Ip",
    "w@Ip",
    "x@Ip",
    "y@Ip",
    "z@Ip"
)
```

Why do I get this? Is there a better way to do this? 
PS: Sometimes this crashes with "insertObject:atIndex:" can not insert nil object.... Why?

Comment: A "character string" is supposed to be null-terminated.  Yours isn't, so stringWithCString blindly reads ahead until it encounters a random zero byte.

Comment: The single quotes are used to create character constants, double quotes are used to create strings that are nu terminated.

Comment: Keep in mind that "a-z" as lowercase letters is only valid for some languages. Other languages have either additional or completely different lowercase letters. Keep that in mind when you consider that your app may be used by people from all over the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from dasblinkenlight, another approach is

```
for (unichar crt = 'a'; crt <= 'z'; crt ++) // note crt is now unichar
{
    NSString *chrStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters: &crt length: 1];
    [lowerCaseLetters addObject:chrStr];
}
```

Following on from user2734323 another approach is

```
lowerCaseLetters = [@[ @"a", @"b", @"c",  .... , @"x", @"y", @"z" ] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior:

```
NSString *chrStr = [NSString stringWithCString:&crt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem is that `&crt` is *not* a C string, because C strings must be null-terminated. You can fix it like this:

```
char buf[2];
buf[0] = crt;
buf[1] = '\0';
NSString *chrStr = [NSString stringWithCString:buf encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You could also use `stringWithFormat:` for a simpler approach, like this:

```
NSString *chrStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", crt];
```

Comment: The last approach looks really nice!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
NSString *stringWithComma = @"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z";
NSArray *lowerCaseLetters = [[NSArray new] init];

lowerCaseLetters = [stringWithComma componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];
NSLog(@"Array %@",lowerCaseLetters);
```

This gives you an NSArray. If you need a NSMutableArray, you have to copy from the NSArray.

or simply allocate

```
NSMutableArray *lowerCaseLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"a", @"b",...,@"z", nil];
```

The first approach is dynamic though as you could create stringWithComma dynamically with any values in it.